# SqlAlchemy Selectable distinct of combination of columns

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a view in SqlAlchemy based on the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, map_id FROM record;
```

In records there can be various user_id and map_id combinations. Also multiple entries of the same ids are possible.

I currently have the following code

```
class UserFinishedMaps(db.Model):
    __table__ = create_view(
        name="user_finished_maps",
        selectable=select([Record.user_id, Record.map_id]).distinct(
            Record.user_id, Record.map_id
        ),
        metadata=db.metadata,
    )
```

This obviously does not work. I am trying to figure out which the correct syntax for the selectable would be to matche the above SQL statement.

Comment: Try `select([func.dictinct(Record.user_id)...` perhaps